# Angular 2 RC5 & @angular/router 3.0.0-rc.1 Invalid configuration or a bug?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

In this case I encounter this issue using RC5 of Angular 2 and latest router.

My routes.ts file is this:

```
import {
  provideRouter,
  Routes,
  RouterModule
}
from '@angular/router';
import {
  OverviewComponent,
  LoginComponent,
  ProfileComponent
} from './shared';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { HasToken } from './common/index';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/login'
  }
];

export const authProviders = [AuthGuard, HasToken];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  authProviders
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

And my app.module.ts file (bootstrap) is this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {appRouterProviders, routing} from './routes';
import {
  OverviewComponent,
  LoginComponent,
  ProfileComponent
} from './shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    // Router
    routing,
    // Forms
    FormsModule,
  ],
    providers: [
      appRouterProviders,
        provide(AuthHttp, {
         useFactory: (http) => {
           return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
             headerName: 'Authorization',
             headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
             tokenName: 'token',
             tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('token')),
             globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}],
             noJwtError: false,
             noTokenScheme: false
           }), http);
          },
        deps: [Http]
       })
     ],      entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

And finally my entry file (main.ts) is this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AppModule, environment } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

So when I'm running the `ng-serve` (it's an angular-cli with webpack project) Im getting this error in console:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Invalid configuration of route ' ': one of the following must be provided (component or redirectTo or children or loadChildren)

**UPDATE CODE AND NEW ERROR**

> Uncaught Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

**LATEST UPDATE**

It seems that there is an issue with the barrels. If I import the components to the `app.module` it by-pass this  error but giving an other one:

> uri.match is not a function

I tried of course to add the `pathMatch` attribute in routes but nothing changes.

Comment: It seems that there is an issue of angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10595

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My problem was quite simple after all (tried so many hours).

Solution:
**Do not import components from barrels**
Import them directly from their folders.

That solved my problem.

Update:

Also about the `undefined` error the problem was that not all of my components was declared in the `imports` of the app.module.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what exactly fixed what. Could you post a before/after comparaison ?

Comment: Yes I'll do it later today

Comment: I had the same error, after importing components directly I don't have this error anymore

Comment: I'm also getting:

Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

I'm pretty confident I'm not loading from barrels.  I noticed that if I remove my declarations line, my code then complains about undefined for the providers.  I suspect this is systemjs related, but not sure how. Of course everything worked great with RC4.

Comment: @user1637302 you haven't declare in your appmodule imports your components. Add them and you'll be ready to go ;)

Comment: Just not importing components from barrels seems to me more like a workaround than an actual explanation of what could be going on. According to [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-10) a barrel should re export all its subsequent barrels. [I opened up an issue in the repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831)

Comment: I agree @caroso1222 but the issue is this. I read another issue except yours so I'm guessing a fix will be there in the next release (hopefully).

Comment: One of my developers had this error message today and it turned out that he still had the module.id's set in his components which are not used since the webpack update as they are system.js specific. Did you copy over from a previous angular CLI deployment?

Comment: @NeilYoung yes you should not have it in your component both module.id and directives

Answer (score 1):

Your imports for the AppModule has duplicates RoutingModule declarations. Also there is no need to import CommonModule as it is already exported by the BrowserModule.

Try to change your imports from:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    // Router
    RouterModule,
    routing,
    // Forms
    FormsModule,
 ],
```

To this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    FormsModule
 ],
```

Comment: Check my answer that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still have this problem, if you define a route for a component and then define your component at the bottom of the page, it throws this error.

Basically , this error means the provided component for the route is undefined .

So move the component class to be before the routes or if your importing it , make sure it's been imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your casting your routes wrong.  You need to import Routes.

```
import { Routes,provideRouter, RouterConfig, RouterModule '@angular/router';
```

And instead of creating a RouterConfig,

```
const routes: RouterConfig = []
```

Use Routes instead.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = []
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thought so and tried that already. In this case still I'm getting: >Uncaught Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import these

```
provideRouter, RouterConfig
```

nor required this code

```
export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  authProviders
];
```

and

```
appRouterProviders,
```

instead change the type of routes to Routes which is required to import

that's it.

Comment: I'm getting the issue here but still the same issue :/

Comment: If I remove from my `app.module` those declarations the    ```OverviewComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProfileComponent```
then I get the first error, otherwise I'm getting the second error of my question